# List of 20 elements that returns the least amount of recursive calls using quicksort

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

So I've gathered that this method will cause QuickSort to make the MOST number of recursive calls:

```
  public static List<Integer> input() {
    return Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
```

but I would like to do the opposite. I'm a student and newb so any level of help is appreciated!

Comment: [An example of Best Case Scenario for Quick Sort (Need someone to check if my answer is correct)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9141172/12323248), [Quick Sort Time Complexity Best Case Input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57693117/12323248), [Java QuickSort Best Case Array Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32556521/12323248): One of these should help you.

Comment: This depends on how you select the pivot.

Comment: If all the data elements are the same, then [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) will result in the fewest recursive calls: ceil(log2(n)). If a 3 partition scheme is used, elements < pivot, elements == pivot, elements, elements > pivot, then zero recursive calls are made.

Comment: Are you asking for *lowest call nesting depth* or *lowest total number of calls*? Does the implementation exclude the pivot position?

Comment: @maraca - in the questions case where all the elements == 0, it doesn't matter how the pivot is selected. It's a worst case scenario for [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) and best case scenario (fewest number of recursive calls) for [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) .