# What is the Best Input Array for Quick Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am working to find the best performing input array for quicksort.  My array is to be 100 elements long consisting of integers 1 thru 100.  I am choosing the last element as the pivot value.

I know I want the last element to be 50 so that I get two subarrays of equal length.  I then know I want element 49 to be 25 so that I get another event split.

I am a little confused as to where to put that original 25 so that after the first split it is in position 49.  Can anyone help me understand the algorithm a little better?

I am not necessarily looking for an example, but an explanation on how to achieve the positions.  I would like the answer for 10,100,1000... length array.

Comment: ...why are you using your last element as pivot? You probably want to give https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort a read-over.

Comment: For 100 elements, you would be very hard-pressed to actually measure any difference between any common sort algorithm on modern hardware.

Comment: It is not necessarily a performance thing as much as an understanding of the algorithm.  I just don't quite get where the second set of pivot values are located in relation to the original array.

Comment: Sedgewick has a great video on quicksort: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkD7rPfYMgI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An example of Best Case Scenario for Quick Sort (Need someone to check if my answer is correct)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141172/an-example-of-best-case-scenario-for-quick-sort-need-someone-to-check-if-my-ans)

Comment: Choosing the last element as pivot, or choosing the first, yields a worst case  behavior **O(n^2)** for sorted and reverse sorted arrays.  It is a **very** bad choice of pivot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best case for Quicksort using last element as pivot is the post-order traversal of the balanced binary search tree. For example:

```
     5
   /   \
  3      7
 / \    / \
1   4  6   8
```

The post-order traversal of this binary tree is

```
1 4 3 6 8 7 5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.